# How can I infer a new document against Mahout TopicModel output?

Tags: machine-learning, mahout, lda, inference, topic-modeling

Given a topic model from Mahout LDA CVB program/offline batch execution,
I like to infer a new document using the model/online web service calls.

These documents are not incrediably helpful for new-ing and infer-ing.
* https://builds.apache.org/job/Mahout-Quality/javadoc/org/apache/mahout/clustering/lda/cvb/TopicModel.html
* http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/mahout/trunk/core/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/clustering/lda/cvb/TopicModel.java?view=markup

I couldn't even find any sample code on the Internet or somewhere.

Here, I thought that I might want to do in Java code,

`TopicModel model = new TopicModel();`

`Vector documentInTermFrequency = new RandomAccessSparseVector();`
`documentInTermFrequence.setQuick(termIdX, 10);`
`documentInTermFrequence.setQuick(termIdY, 20);`

`Vector docTopic = new DenseVector(new Double[10] { 0.1, 0.1, ..., 0.1 }); // 0.1 probabilities`

`Vector documentTopicInference = model.infer(documentInTermFrequence, docTopic);`

I haven't seen anyone who tried something like this? Has anyone ever tried something like this?

Any suggestion or pointer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: have you solved this problem?